# How to create categories from image titles when using ImageDataBunch.from_folder()?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, fast-ai

When using ImageDataBunch.from_name_re(), fastAI takes care of creating the categories by using the name of each image. We simply have to input a regex string like this:

`file_parse = r'/([^/]+)_\d+\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$'`

Is there a way to do this when using ImageDataBunch.from_folder()?

```
np.random.seed(42)
data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder('/content/Food-101/images', train='/content/Food-101/images/train', test='/content/Food-101/images/test', valid_pct=0.2, ds_tfms=get_transforms(), size=224)
data.normalize(imagenet_stats)
```

Because when I am running epocs, this is what fastAI is giving me:

```
epoch   train_loss  valid_loss  error_rate  time
0       0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    21:05
1       0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    20:43
2       0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    20:38
3       0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    19:38
4       0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    20:01
```

I believe this is because my `file_parse` variable isn’t used anywhere.